# access variables in nodejs

Tags: node.js, variables, scope

Im an experienced coder in C# and now I´ve to deal with nodejs .. and I cannot get things to work as I expected them to work :)

I have a "class" declared like this :

```
var Gpio;

function Lights()
{
    [.more variables declared the same way..]
    this.o1 = "";
    this.o2 = "";
}

//then I have some methods added like this:
Lights.prototype.Init = function()
{
    var Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio,
    //init of my variables
    o1 = new Gpio(17, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT}),
    o2 = new Gpio(18, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
}

//then I have other methods that try to use o1 and o2 
//that where already defined and initialiced

Lights.prototype.On = function(id)
{
    if(id == 1)
        o1.digitalWrite(true);
    else if(id == 2)
        o2.digitalWrite(true);
}
```

But when I run it I get :

```
o1.digitalWrite(false);
^

ReferenceError: o1 is not defined
```

How can I make those o1 o2 o3 accesibles by the methods ???

Comment: Why would you use `this.o1` in one place but not the rest?

Comment: because If I use it anywhere other than in the constructor I get this; `                this.i1 = new Gpio(25, {    -   SyntaxError: Unexpected token this
`

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. example?

Comment: I copied from the console... Should I post the whole actual block of code ? Maybe something I overwiew and thought was not related is actually messing things up ...  Should I ?

Comment: Just that one line might be enough, `this.o1.foo(...` in those specific places should work fine.

Comment: as I said before, When I tried that I got `this.i1 = new Gpio(25, { - SyntaxError: Unexpected token this` It does not like the "this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Java, C# and other languages, in JavaScript, **the `this` keyword is not optional when accessing instance variables**.

You are getting a `ReferenceError` because there is no variable named `o1` in the current scope.

Try changing it to:

```
Lights.prototype.On = function(id)
{
    if(id == 1)
        this.o1.digitalWrite(true);
    else if(id == 2)
        this.o2.digitalWrite(true);
}
```

(Of course, you'll need to change the `Init` method too)

As a final note, nodeJS supports ES6 which includes [class declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) - they make JS code a lot neater (and more like C#) which might help you.

Here's how I would code your class:

```
const Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio;

class Lights {
    constructor() {
        // there's no need to explicitly declare o1 and o2 here - they'll get 
        // created whenever they are assigned to. This is just for readability.
        this.o1 = null;
        this.o2 = null;
        // add any more properties here in the constructor - you can't
        // declare them in the class body like C#
        this.another = 5;
    }

    init() {
        // I'm assuming there's a reason you haven't done this in the constructor
        this.o1 = new Gpio(17, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT}),
        this.o2 = new Gpio(18, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
    }

    on(id) {
        // this assumes that init() has been called
        switch (id) {
          case 1: this.o1.digitalWrite(true); break;
          case 2: this.o2.digitalWrite(true); break;
        }
    }

    // methods can be static too
    static HELLO() {
       // you would call this method with Lights.HELLO()
       console.log('hello');
    }
}    

// if you need to access the Lights class from another nodejs source file, you'll
// need to export it (there's a few ways to do this, so read the docs)
exports.Lights = Lights;

// in main.js - import the Lights class and instantiate it
const Lights = require('./lights.js').Lights;
var light = new Lights();
light.init();
light.on(1);
// also note, there's no visibility restrictions in JS - all
//  properties and methods are public.
console.log(light.another);
```

If you know C#, this should be fairly easy to follow.

Comment: if you could add an example of a simple classe with a couple of properties (or any kind of public variable) and a method. And how you call it from the main.js I would LOVE it. Thanks for your time

Comment: @javirs added example

Comment: It works, I have problems accessing the var light from inside one event, like `io.on("connection", function(){ HERE });` I solved it making everything static. Any better aproach ?